# HighCharts : display label only on line combine chart

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I use HighChart to display chart. I've done a combine chart with bar and line. It works well but I want to display label only on line and not on bar , but I don't manage.

Here my code to display label :

```
 plotOptions: {
       series: {
         dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
           }
  },
```

With "series" option I have labels on every type of chart (bar and line).

```
 plotOptions: {
       line: {
         dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
           }
  },
```

With "line" option I have no labels.

So, is there a possibility to display label only on one type of chart  ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work for you? See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CpXht/1/).  I am guessing one of your other config options is hiding the labels (or moving them somewhere where they can't be seen, or setting their font color to the same as the background...etc.)

```
 $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        plotOptions: {
            line: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type:'line',
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2]
        }, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: [22.9, 55.5, 134.4]
        }]

    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help...  I fixed the problem. I used line instead of spline, but I still have a little problem , I don't have a label on the last value !

Comment: @archipelago use crop parameter http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.crop